# Java Callout action Class testJar.CustomXpath does not exist

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, pojo, oracle-service-bus

I'm trying to convert the java class to jar file to consume it in Oracle service bus, but when i'm trying to deploy the code im getting below error

```
[PipelinePairNode1, Request Pipeline, stage1, Java Callout action] Class testJar.CustomXpath does not exist
```

Below is my Java class,

```
    package testJar;

public class CustomXpath {
    public CustomXpath() {
        super();
    }

    public static String greeting(String name) {
        return "Hi "+name;
    }
}
```

What is the right method to export to jar with .class files, where i'm going wrong.

This issue is at deployment time only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by creating a maven project and exporting the jar by using below command.

```
mvn clean install
```

1. create maven project
2. select packaging as jar
3. build -> mvn clean install
4. generated jar you may use in OSB for java callout activity.

Hope this method helps if anyone is facing issue.